# Signing New Work Document Regarding Prior Inventions

Tags: legal

I just accepted a new job at a company and they want me to sign a prior inventions form. There is an option to attach prior inventions so they can be excluded. I have YouTube videos, Udemy courses, articles that I publish on Medium etc.

What should I include in the prior inventions sections?

Comment: Do you have any inventions? Things that you have patented? Does the form or any other related form ask about outside activities?

Comment: I don't have anything patented. My prior inventions or work is only YouTube videos, Udemy courses, Medium articles etc. For outside activities, they have a separate form which just says that it should not interfere with your current job.

Comment: Could those courses, videos, articles clash with anything your company is doing?

Comment: At the company I teach web development. But my courses are iOS development.

Comment: It seems to me that none of what you've stated would qualify as inventions. They may be legally protected works (or they may not be), but I think it would be a stretch to call them inventions and they probably wouldn't meet the legal requirements to be considered inventions.

Comment: Thanks! I understand. They are just videos and articles not really any inventions.

Comment: I'd list them anyway.  A lot of these documents define "inventions" as any form of IP.  Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 8):

> I have YouTube videos, Udemy courses, articles that I publish on
> Medium etc.
>
> What should I include in the prior inventions sections?

Include your YouTube videos, Udemy courses that you created (not courses that you just took), articles that you published on Medium, etc.

They may or may not matter, but there's no disadvantage to listing absolutely everything.

Comment: But there are 100's of youtube video I created and also 100's of courses. I can't list all of them and also what about future courses that I will create.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Discuss with a lawyer, not your employer.  Your employer can gain a benefit by lying (a possible right to their previous IP).  A lawyer will protect you.

Answer (score 4):

I would just not sign the form. Hopefully it will just go away.

If it became an issue I would ask for clarification before signing anything on what constitutes an invention in terms of the document, and what it is to be used for. Then at least I would have a better understanding to base my actions on.

Comment: Can I create a very broad inventions documents which just say something in the lines of "Current and future Items created by [Name] and published in any form including but not limited to videos, audio, publications, articles are solely owned by [Name]. "